# image in javascript from variable

Tags: javascript, image, variables, tags

i am trying to get html code for image, but i can't find mistake.

image is in image/NY.gif

NY.gif is stored in variable COA
here is piece of code

```
txt="<img src=\"image/"+COA+"\">" "<strong>Name: </strong>" + Name + "<br />"
```

Comment: try using single quotes for the attributes inside the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is because of a copy / paste into this site, but you don't have anything joining the img tag part of your string and the strong tag part. I think you need to remove both quotes around the empty space between the two. Failing that, get debugging with Firefox & Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You have no closing double quote `"` at the end of the line, for one thing.

Comment: second part of code is working, withou the first "<img src=\"image/"+COA+"\">"    i have edited it in question :)